# Wordpress "Frontend Dashboard custom post and taxonomy" plugin not allow to add featured image

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used Frontend Dashboard custom post and taxonomy to add the custome posts from user dashboard , everything works fine but featured image not image option not works to upload an image for the perticular  post.
what should i do , please help me !

Comment: _“what should i do”_ - you should _start_ by reading [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to find within your plugin "register_post_type" supports parameter:

You need to add :

```
'supports' => array( 'thumbnail' )
```

Comment: Hello Sir , Thank you so much  for instant reply .. but where should i add this snippest , can you plz tell me more

Comment: find this within your plugin register_post_type and add support tag

'supports' => array( 'thumbnail' )

Comment: Thats working sir , Thank you so much

Comment: That's great to hear that it works for you ! You're welcome !